# JQGrid MultiSelect getting the column data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way for the JQGrid to return an array of column Data for using multiSelect as opposed to just an array of rowIds ?

At the moment I can only return the last column data that was selected.

```
jQuery("#buttonSelected").click(function() {

           var ids = jQuery("#relatedSearchGrid").getGridParam('selarrrow');
           var count = ids.length;

           for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

           var columnData = $("#relatedSearchGrid").find("tbody")[0].rows[$("#relatedSearchGrid").getGridParam('selrow') - 1].cells[1].innerHTML;

               alert("In the loop and  " + columnData );

           }

           if (count == 0) return;
           var posturl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~") %>Rel******/AddSelected****/' + ids;
           if (confirm("Add these " + count + " Docs?")) {
               $.post(posturl,
               { ids: columnData },
               function() { jQuery("#relatedSearchGrid").trigger("reloadGrid") },
            "json");
           }


       })
```

Answer (score 5):

Use getRowData to get the data for each row:

```
var rowData = $("#relatedSearchGrid").getRowData(ids[i]);

var colData = rowData.Name_Of_Your_Column;
```

Comment: Thanks Justin for the speedy, concise and correct solution.

You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: what if my column name has spaces or '/'  in it?

Comment: @VishnudevK - No problem, just use the syntax `rowData['Name_Of_Your_Column']`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var userListjqGrid = $('#UserListGrid'),
        selRowId = userListjqGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
        userId = userListjqGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'UserId'),
        userName = userListjqGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'UserName'),
        subIds = $(subgridTableId).getGridParam('selarrrow'),
        accessRuleIds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < subIds.length; i++) {
        accessRuleIds[i] = $(subgridTableId).getRowData(subIds[i]).AccessRuleId;
    }
```